# Can you use a CURSOR in WHERE statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure `loyalty_raise` that is suppoused to increase salary for every eligible employee (determined by a function `eligible_for_raise`, based on time worked). I declared a cursor to store all the id's of eligible employees, and tried to update the table

```
PROCEDURE loyalty_raise IS       
        CURSOR c_eligible_emps IS
            SELECT employeeId
            FROM Employees
            WHERE eligible_for_raise(employeeId) = 1;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_eligible_emps;
        UPDATE Employees
        SET salary = salary + (salary * (salary_raise_multiplier / 100))
        WHERE employeeId IN c_eligible_emps;
        CLOSE c_eligible_emps;
    END loyalty_raise;
```

But it gives me an error: `PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "C_ELIGIBLE_EMPS": invalid identifier`

Comment: Have a look at some cursor examples. The syntax is ```OPEN, FETCH, CLOSE```. You're just opening and closing it. A cursor is not an array, it is a pointer to a resultset (rows) so you have to iterate through it and ```WHERE employeeId IN c_eligible_emps``` doesn't work.

Comment: What does the title of your post have to do with your question ? There is no cursor in the where clause - it is a function.

Comment: @KoenLostrie i know that one way, would be to iterate through the cursor, and do update based on that, but i want to avoid it here.

Comment: Do you really need a cursor ? It can be done in a single statement without cursor.

Comment: Yes. Specifics of my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your task correctly, it might be the `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause you're looking for.

I'm using Scott's sample schema, raising salaries for employees whose current salary is lower than 2000.

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function eligible_for_raise (par_empno in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_sal number;
  5  begin
  6    select sal into l_sal
  7    from emp
  8    where empno = par_empno;
  9    return case when l_sal < 2000 then 1 else 0 end;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Procedure: pay attention to cursor's `FOR UPDATE` clause (line #6), as well as `UPDATE`s `WHERE CURRENT OF` (line #16):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure loyalty_raise as
  2    cursor c_eligible_emps is
  3      select empno
  4      from emp
  5      where eligible_for_raise(empno) = 1
  6      for update;
  7    ceer c_eligible_emps%rowtype;
  8  begin
  9    open c_eligible_emps;
 10    loop
 11      fetch c_eligible_emps into ceer;
 12      exit when c_eligible_emps%notfound;
 13
 14      update emp set
 15        sal = sal + 0.1
 16        where current of c_eligible_emps;
 17    end loop;
 18    close c_eligible_emps;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: this is initial data:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal from emp order by sal desc;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000
      7902 FORD             3000
      7788 SCOTT            3000
      7566 JONES            2975
      7698 BLAKE            2850
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7499 ALLEN            1600      --> Allen, Turner, etc. should get a raise
      7844 TURNER           1500
      7934 MILLER           1300
      7521 WARD             1250
      7654 MARTIN           1250
      7876 ADAMS            1100
      7900 JAMES             950
      7369 SMITH             800

14 rows selected.
```

Run the procedure:

```
SQL> exec loyalty_raise;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Check the result:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal from emp order by sal desc;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000
      7902 FORD             3000
      7788 SCOTT            3000
      7566 JONES            2975
      7698 BLAKE            2850
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7499 ALLEN          1600.1    --> Right; Allen, Turner etc. really got a raise
      7844 TURNER         1500.1
      7934 MILLER         1300.1
      7521 WARD           1250.1
      7654 MARTIN         1250.1
      7876 ADAMS          1100.1
      7900 JAMES           950.1
      7369 SMITH           800.1

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a cursor variable and `BULK COLLECT`. That way the cursor result populates a collection that can then be referenced with the `TABLE` function in a where clause.

Example on the EMP/DEPT dataset with a dummy eligible_for_raise function and an anonymous pl/sql block:

```
koen>CREATE FUNCTION eligible_for_raise (empno emp.empno%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    RETURN 1;
  5  END;
  6* /

Function ELIGIBLE_FOR_RAISE compiled

koen>CREATE TYPE emp_arr IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  2* /

Type EMP_ARR compiled

koen>select sal from emp where ename = 'KING';

    SAL 
_______ 
   5001 

koen>DECLARE
  2     my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3    
  4     l_emps emp_arr; 
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN my_cursor FOR 'SELECT empno FROM emp WHERE eligible_for_raise(empno) = 1';  
  7    
  8     FETCH my_cursor  
  9     BULK COLLECT INTO l_emps;  
 10     CLOSE my_cursor;     
 11     
 12     UPDATE emp SET sal = sal + 1 WHERE empno IN (SELECT * FROM table(l_emps));
 13     
 14     
 15  END;
 16* /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

koen>select sal from emp where ename = 'KING';

    SAL 
_______ 
   5002 

koen>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. You must previosly convert cursor to table type variable. If you suppose big amount of records (millions) - you must previously convert cursor to global temporary table.